# Why is this value 0? Weird behaviour of my smart contract

Tags: solidity

I'm stuck with a very weird behaviour of my smart contract.

```
  uint weiDue = calculateTotalWei(winningBets[i].tokensDeposited, winningBets[i].amounts, multipliers) / totalWeiBetWinningTeam * totalWeiBetLosingTeam;

  //debugging
  weiDueEv(calculateTotalWei(winningBets[i].tokensDeposited, winningBets[i].amounts, multipliers), totalWeiBetWinningTeam, totalWeiBetLosingTeam, weiDue);
```

The function **calculateTotalWei** returns uint and both **totalWeiBetWinningTeam** and **totalWeiBetLosingTeam** are also uints.

After debugging with **event** it seems like

> `weiDue = 100 / 200 * 1700 // gives 0, should be 850`

on the other hand

> `weiDue = 100 / 100 * 1700 // gives 1700`

What is this magic behaviour and how do I fix this? It seems like 100/200 is coerced to 0 before multipling by 1700 but why?

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does not support decimals, so when you do `100 / 200` it uses ["integer division"](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html), where the floor function is used to determine the final value.

In this case `.5` is reduced to `0`.

Comment: How is it then if I create test function:
    `function calc() public view returns (uint) {
        uint x = 100/200 * 1700;
        
        return x;
    }`

it returns 850

Comment: It is not clear what your `calculateTotalWei` function is doing. Can you please paste that code? Can you make sure the value returned from that is not zero?

Comment: Look at the behavior of `function print(uint x) public pure returns(uint) { return x / 10 * 20; }` You will see this function returns 0 for values of x less than 10.

Answer (score 1):

Any integer division is 0 if the denominator (i.e. the number below in the fraction) is greater than the denominator (i.e. the other number) because any number following the decimal do not exist:

100/200 should be 0.50, but zeroing all the digit after the decimal, because they do not exist in the integer representation, it is zero.

To have proper execution the best practice is to premultiply any numerator for a big number and to divide for the same number the final result of the operation.

```
weiDue = 100 / 200 * 1700  is 0
```

but

```
weidue = ((100 * 1000) / 200 * 1700) / 1000 = 850
```

In this particular case if you change the order of the operation, multiplying all first and dividing as last operation, you have:

```
weidue = (100 * 1700) / 200 = 850
```

without further elaboration.

In general, when using integer math, you prefer to have the division as the latest operation to perform.

Remember that the natural order of execution of operation of same priority is from left to right, as encountered in the instruction, but some brackets somewhere do not cost money or gas, so use it.